# Resend Activation Link not sending

Tags: users, user-profile

I am having an issue where the activation link sent to a user has expired and when they click the 'resend activation link' on the warning message a new activation link is never sent.

I have added logging into the `userservice->sendActivationEmail` method to see if it's called and it never gets called.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Per Brad's response, this appears to have been a bug in Craft (with a fix in place and pending release). Closing as a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a bug and just fixed it for the next release.